# How to use 2 different global git configs?

Tags: git, config, global, commit

I am using the github client and sourcetree by atlassian. I wanted to use 2 different global git configs for each software.

At the moment I have to edit and check every commit my autor and email name.

So how can I specify a unique config for each git program that I use.

king regards

Comment: Are you working in 2 different repos?

Comment: Yes i work in 2 different repos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each repo has its own configuration, which can override the system-wide and global configurations.
Just enter each repo and

```
git config user.name xxxx
git config user.email yyyy
```

Note the lack of the `--global` option.

Comment: Thanks for this fast answer, but is there solution without to use the git shell? Sourcetree & Github Client are both GUI based and i never use the git shell.

Comment: Then you could look up their Help and find out how to set configuration options. I've never used any of them, so I don't know. But I hope my answer will help you find the right options.

Comment: @TheAllSeeingEye any Git client worth its value will/should properly reference the local git config.

Answer (score 0):

I was inspired by the answer of SzG. That is my final solution:

At first have a look for the global git config. You find the `.gitconfig` inside your home directory (on windows: `%userprofile%\.gitconfig`, on linux: `~/.gitconfig`).

I created 2 Batches in the directory of the global git config file.

GitHub.bat & SourceTree.bat

**GitHub.bat**

```
@echo off
cd /D %userprofile%
del .gitconfig
copy GitHub.bat .gitconfig
```

**GitHub**

```
[user]
    name = Name1
    email = email1@example.com
[core]
    autocrlf = true
    excludesfile = C:\\Users\\{windowsusername}\\Documents\\gitignore_global.txt
```

**SourceTree.bat**

```
@echo off
cd /D %userprofile%
del .gitconfig
copy SourceTree.bat .gitconfig
```

**SourceTree**

```
[user]
    name = Name2
    email = email2@example.com
[core]
    autocrlf = true
    excludesfile = C:\\Users\\{windowsusername}\\Documents\\gitignore_global.txt
```

So this is working fine, just have to run one of these batches before commiting and i can use 2 different autor names with different email.